# How to choose spring boot parent version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm quite new to Spring Boot and I'm not sure on which version is preferable to use.
In particular, I don't know if it's better to choose a RELEASE version ( that should be more stable, but has a nearer End Of Life ) or one of the last version.

For example, which version of Spring Boot Starter Parent is better to use between:

2.3.12.RELEASE  ( End of life :  February 2022 )

2.5.2 ( End of life: February 2023)

Thank's a lot for any response/advice.

Comment: 2.5.2 is a release version as well. The RELEASE part has been dropped since Spring Boot 2.3 after that it is just 2.4.1 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My rule of thumb - if you don't have any limitation (dependencies or such), always take the latest. more features/bugfixes/etc.

and the release in the name is meaningless, they are both valid stable versions

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the latest stable version of spring(in this moment is the 2.5.3). The RELEASE part in the name is not used anymore, just be careful to don't use the "SNAPSHOT" version, sometimes those are unstable.